# How to test for significant differences in R?

Tags: r, anova

I want to test whether there are differences in the parameters of the Bass diffusion model (m, p, q) for Food products compared to Non-food products. My data looks as follows (including 3223 products, both food and nonfood and many more variables such as product category etc.):

```
   barcode     m          p           q           Food    
   12000028632 35.299941  0.028328659 0.246649286 Food
  672935819363 26.714539  0.037432801 0.003112476 Nonfood
```

I want to find out whether the m, p and q of Food products are significantly different from Non-food products. I thought ANOVA would be the best to do that, but when I perform an ANOVA test:

```
anova(lm(p ~ Food , TotalBassModel1))
```

I get this output, which does not say anything:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: p
            Df Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
Food         1 0.0137 0.0137247  10.783 0.001035 **
Residuals 3221 4.0998 0.0012728                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Who has a suggestion how to do this type of analysis?

Comment: You get a p value of 0.001035, so the output does say something. The real questions are: what are you looking to compare? Average values? Something else? Why? Which is the most appropriate test based on your data and your objectives?

Comment: Yes, but not what I want to measure. The thing is, I want to see whether people adopt products for food products sooner than for non-food products, for which I needed the p and q parameters of the Bass model. But now, I need to test whether these values are significantly different. Therefore, I thought the ANOVA test would help me, do you have other suggestions? @AntoniosK

Comment: That p value shows a statistically significant difference in `p` average values between your two `Food` groups. Nothing more, because of the test you've chosen. `p` looks like a continuous variable and `Food` has two groups. Check the `t.test` approach, but also the assumptions involved wit that....

Comment: Besides @AntoniosK comment, you might additionally consider to use logistic regression (or similar) to see how your three variables are simultaneously related to the binary outcome food/non-food.

Answer (score 3):

The `aov()` and `lm()` functions generate a model object that contains quite a bit of data beyond the F-table for the analysis of variance that was in the original post. Of particular importance are the model coefficients.  Without the coefficients we can't see whether the `food` or `non-food` products have a lower coefficient of innovation (the `p` parameter in the Bass diffusion model). In order to see the coefficients in an ANOVA model, one must save the model object and extract them.

Analysis of Variance is useful when the data conforms to the [linear model assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Assumptions_of_ANOVA), including:

- Independence of observations
- Normal distribution of dependent variable & residuals
- Homogeneity of variances: variance of dependent variable is same across groups

As an example, we will use the Crampton 1947 ToothGrowth data to assess whether supplement type (Orange Juice vs. Vitamin C) lead to different rates of growth in guinea pig odontoblasts, including printing of the model coefficients.

The null hypothesis is that there is no difference in growth of odontoblasts when guinea pigs are given Vitamin C versus Orange Juice. Our alternate hypothesis is that the growth rates are different. We'll set the rejection region for the null hypothesis at alpha = 0.05, meaning that we're willing to take a risk of rejecting the null hypothesis 5% of the time when it is actually true.

Here is the R code required for this analysis:

```
library(datasets)
data(ToothGrowth)
aModel <- aov(len ~ supp,data=ToothGrowth)
summary(aModel)
aModel$coefficients
```

...and the output.

```
> aModel <- aov(len ~ supp,data=ToothGrowth)
> summary(aModel)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
supp         1    205  205.35   3.668 0.0604 .
Residuals   58   3247   55.98                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> aModel$coefficients
(Intercept)      suppVC  
   20.66333    -3.70000 
>
```

### How do we interpret the output?

First, the Pr(>F) value of 0.0604 is greater than 0.05, our alpha level. Therefore, we fail to reject the null hypothesis that the supplement type (orange juice vs. vitamin C) leads to larger tooth growth in guinea pigs.

Second, the coefficients tell us that the average growth for guinea pigs given orange juice is 20.6633 microns, and that the impact of giving vitamin C instead of orange juice was -3.70 microns.

Note that in this specific analysis, a second variable, `dose` explains the effect of `supp` on `len`. I cover this in a more detailed article, [Commentary of ToothGrowth Factorial ANOVA](http://rpubs.com/lgreski/toothgrowthanova), where I compare the use of `t-test()` with `aov()` referencing an analysis from Robert Kabacoff's *R in Action*.

### Using t.test()

As noted by one of the comments on the original post, `t.test()` may also be used for this type of analysis, and the output is somewhat easier to interpret than the output from `aov()`.

```
oj <- ToothGrowth[ToothGrowth$supp =="OJ",1]
vc <- ToothGrowth[ToothGrowth$supp =="VC",1]
t.test(oj,vc,alternative="two.sided",
       conf.level=0.95)
```

...and the output:

```
> t.test(oj,vc,alternative="two.sided",
+        conf.level=0.95)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  oj and vc
t = 1.9153, df = 55.309, p-value = 0.06063
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1710156  7.5710156
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 20.66333  16.96333
```

From the output we see that the `oj` vector has a mean of 20.66, and the `vc` vector has a mean of 16.96, or 3.7 less than `oj`. Since 0 is included in the 95% confidence interval, we fail to reject the null hypothesis that tooth growth in guinea pigs is different when they are given orange juice versus a supplement of vitamin C.